# The effect of spring constant $k$ (N/mm) on period, frequency under water (no mass attached with spring)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, frequency, spring, flow

springs having different stiffness (N/mm) attached with cylinder of specific diameter in open channel flow (water) fully submerged in water. the direction of the spring and flowing water are inline.
what will be the behavior of time period, frequency of different spring if we increases the flow velocity?
with increasing flow velocity, spring having less stiffness will go for high amplitude/frequency or spring having more stiffness?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you suppose "with increasing flow velocity, spring having less stiffness "